# Compartilhar Conteúdo no Facebook

Tags: html5, facebook

Para compartilhar um conteúdo no Facebook estou utilizando a API SDK do Facebook.

São artigos no site que terão agora esse recurso de compartilhamento. Estou fazendo assim:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="{!! URL::to('/social/facebook-page/'.$resenha->id) !!}" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name"     content="Teste Eempresa" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="{!! $resenha->concessionaria !!}" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Vejam o que estão falando da concessionária" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="{!! URL::to('images/social/facebook/'.$resenha->foto_facebook) !!}" />
```

Mas não estou conseguindo alterar o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam o que está underlinizado em vermelho.

Eu acreditava ser a propriedade `og:site_name`. Mas mesmo alterando, não muda nada.

Como é um artigo também quero colocar o nome do autor.

Alguém sabe como altero isso ?

Comment: Descobri o que que é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só adicionar essa TAG:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/seu-perfil-facebook" />
```

Mas o valor do `content` **deve** ser um perfil do Facebook.